# указатели c++ , адрес

Tags: c++

могул ли я присвоить указателю сразу адрес , ну типо

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std
int main(){
int*ss =0x7ffeb1a6f768;
cout<<*ss;
}
```

и если да , то можете объяснить как , информации просто 0;
если можете , то напишите в тг :@idea_29

Comment: Вопрос — чего вы хотите этим добиться? Ощущение, что вы спрашиваете, не как гвоздь забить, а в какой руке при этом микроскоп держать... https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/195342

Comment: Легко: `int *ss = (__typeof__(ss))(size_t)0x7ffeb1a6f768ULL;`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы ясно представляете себе что с этим делать (сильно подозреваю что это не так), то можно кастить двумя способами:

```
// C++style cast
int* ss = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x7ffeb1a6f768);
```

и так

```
// C-style cast
ss = (int*)(0x7ffeb1a6f768);
```

А вообще, если возникают такие вопросы, рекомендовал бы какие-нибудь курсы что-ли пройти... Вот к примеру тема [Преобразование типов](https://stepik.org/lesson/53366/step/1?unit=31456) в бесплатном курсе от stepik

Comment: Константу лучше тоже приводить к size_t (иначе, если ее размер окажется меньше размера указателя, некоторые версии компилятора выдают warning)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, но с какими-то изменениями:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* ss = (int*) 0x7ffeb1a6f768;
    cout << ss;
    return 0;
}
```

T.e.

- преобразовать предложенный адрес тоже на тип `int*`:

  ```
  int* ss = (int*) 0x7ffeb1a6f768;
  ```
- для вывода применить не `*ss` (указатель на адрес), а прямо `ss`:

  ```
  cout << ss;
  ```
- и, конечно, вернуть какое-то значение типа `int` - в соответствии с определением функции `main()` как **`int`** `main()`:

  ```
  return 0;
  ```

Comment: Какого такого "длинного адреса"?